# Get html from website

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I can get an html  code from web site this way:

```
public void Test()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += 
        new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://testUrl.xml"));
}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                                    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string html = e.Result;
    //Now do something with the string...
}
```

But I need to get updated html each 30 seconds, so I wrote:

```
public void TestMain()
{

    DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    };
    Timer.Tick += (s, t) =>
    {
        Test();
    };
    Timer.Start();
}
```

I changed the xml but I get the same html, what is wrong?

Comment: maybe you get the same HTML because it hasnt changed since last time?...

Comment: no, of course I change xml file and check that  changes html on the web site)

Comment: are you remembering to refresh the site? sometimes the cache wont refresh so youll never see a difference

Comment: so, if the problem is not refreshing cache, what I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: i never figured that out, sometimes i would wait a couple of minutes and try again and it would work, other times i had to wait forever before my sites would actually realise i had changed the code behind them, god knows why, i just left them to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a cache included in the `WebClient`. If you request the same URI twice, the second time it will fetch the whole content directly from the cache.

There's no way to disable cache on `WebClient`, so you have two workarounds:

- Use `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebClient`
- Add a random parameter to the URI:

  ```
  client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://testUrl.xml?nocache=" + Guid.NewGuid()));
  ```

Comment: thanks, fits right in with the comments i gave him on his question perfectly timed